# What is the usual topology of Cauchy sequences?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

What kind of topology can be induced on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ (Cauchy sequences on $\Bbb Q$), besides trivial ones ?

Comment: Discrete topology I'm sure

Comment: Pick your favourite bijection $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then you see that your question amounts to: "What are the topologies on $\mathbb{R}$"? I guess you have some restrictions in mind? Otherwise you get a lot of topologies.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of introducing a topology on $C(\mathbb Q)$?

Comment: I was wanting to compare the metric-induced topology in $\mathbb{R}$ with the quotient topology (looking at $\Bbb R$ as the Cauchy sequence quotient $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb Q)/{\sim}$, where $(x_n)\sim (y_n) \iff (x_n-y_n)\to 0$). Later, i was thinking that i can introduce a topology in $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb Q)$ such those topologies are equivallent.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches:

- **Cauchy sequences as meaningful objects.** There is a natural map from $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ to $\mathbb{R}$, taking each Cauchy sequence to its limit. The usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then "pulls back" to a topology on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$. This topology is of course not $T_0$, since distinct Cauchy sequences with the same limit are topologically equivalent, but we usually care about equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences instead of individual Cauchy sequences anyways so who cares.

  - Note that this is "ahistorical" - it assumes we've already built $\mathbb{R}$. We can avoid talking about $\mathbb{R}$ directly by instead defining a pseudometric on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ in the obvious way, and then looking at the topology that induces.
- **Cauchy sequences as just sequences.** On the other hand, given any topological space $X$ there is a natural topology on the set $X^\omega$ of sequences of elements of $X$ - the *product topology*. The set $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ then can be viewed as a subspace of the space $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$. This topology is $T_0$ (indeed, metrizable) but is much less natural: it ignores the whole point of Cauchy-ness. (E.g. the set of sequences which don't happen to begin with "$17$" is open in this topology.)

It's easy to check that these topologies are incomparable, which is unsurprising given that they're totally unrelated. In almost every situation, the former is the "right" topology (and indeed the "$T_0$ification" of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ with respect to this topology is more natural than the set $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Q})$ itself).